# About the usage of the strong approximation theorem

Tags: ring-theory, proof-verification, field-theory, valuation-theory

I'm reading Henning Stichtenoth's [Algebraic Function Fields and Codes](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540768777) and at Proposition 3.2.5(a) of section 2, chapter 3 he says:

> Let $\mathcal{O}_S$ be a holomorphy ring of $F/K$. Then $F$ is the quotient filed of $\mathcal{O}_S$.

At the proof he takes an element $0\neq x\in F$ and a place $P_0\in S$. Then he says that **by the Strong Approximation Theorem** there exists an element $z\in F$ such that (the function $v_P:F\to\mathbb{Z}\cup\{\infty\}$ is the valuation function associated with the given place $P$):

$$v_{P_0}(z)=\text{max}\{0,v_P(x^{-1})\}\quad\text{and}\quad v_P(z)\geq\text{max}\{0,v_P(x^{-1})\}\;\forall P\in S\setminus\{P_0\}$$

I can't see why the inequality holds. For you to understand completely I'll
enunciate the Strong Approximation Theorem (Theorem 1.6.5 of the book):

> Let $S\subset\mathbb{P}_F$ be a **proper** subset of $\mathbb{P}_F$ and $P_1,\ldots,P_r\in S$. Suppose there are given elements $x_1,\ldots,x_r\in F$ and integers $n_1,\ldots,n_r\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then there exists an element $x\in F$ such that $$v_{P_i}(x_i)=n_i,\;i=1,\ldots,r\;\text{and}\;v_P(x)\geq0\;\forall P\in S\setminus\{P_1,\ldots,P_r\}$$

Back to Proposition 3.2.5(a), I tried to consider, by the Strong Approximation Theorem, an $\alpha\in F$ such that

$$v_{P_0}(\alpha - x)=\text{max}\{0,v_{P_0}(x)\}\quad\text{and}\quad v_P(\alpha)\geq 0\;\forall P\in S\setminus\{P_0\}$$

and then take $z=\alpha-x$, but that doesn't help so much because, by the Triangle Inequality:
 $$v_P(z)=v_P(\alpha-x)\geq\text{min}\{v_P(\alpha),v_P(-x)\}=\text{min}\{v_P(\alpha),v_P(x)\}$$

So why does that first inequality follow from the Strong Approximation Theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\lbrace P_1,\dotsc,P_r\rbrace$ be the places in $S$ where $v_{P_i}(x^{-1})>0$ (there are only finitely many.) Then the inequalities you wrote are satisfied by any $z$ with
$$v_{P_0}(z)=\max\lbrace 0,v_{P_0}(x^{-1})\rbrace$$
and
$$v_{P_i}(z)=v_{P_i}(x^{-1}),\,\,i=1,\dotsc,r$$
and
$$v_P(z)\geq 0\,\,\textrm{if}\,\,P\in S\backslash\lbrace P_0,P_1,\dotsc,P_r\rbrace.$$
Such a $z$ exists by the strong approximation theorem: The first two inequalities above are from the first inequality in the strong approximation theorem (take the $x_i$'s in that theorem to be zero), and the third inequality above is from the second inequality in the strong approximation theorem.

Comment: Yes! And in case there are no such $P_i$'s the condition is valid too.

Comment: Exactly. And beware, the strong approximation theorem is one of those theorems which when people say "by the strong approximation theorem..." they really mean "by the strong approximation theorem plus some standard arguments...". So you are likely to encounter this usage, or a similar usage of it again.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed various subtleties like these in the book. Unhappily I spent almost the entire last week thinking about this one and couldn't imagine that it was way more simpler than I thought.